# Passing my select id to route controller and show to another blade file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to pass the selected `id` to `controller` using a `route`. But nothing happen shown at another blade file. Here, is my code

my blade contain that script

```
 $("#state").on("change", function() {
            var id = $(this).val();
            console.log(id)
            var cuid = document.getElementById("cu").value;  
            console.log(cuid)

        });
```

> state select

```
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group" id="stateBranch">
                    <label for="sm" class="control-label">{{ __('messages.state') }}</label>
                    <select name="state" id="state" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option value="">{{ __('messages.select') }}</option>

                      @if(!empty(request()->session()->get('stateList')))
                                    @foreach(request()->session()->get('stateList') as $state)
                                        <option value="{{ $state->st_state_code }}">{{ $state->st_state_desc }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif
                    </select>

        </div>
```

> cu select

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group" id="custbranchreport">
                    <label for="sm" class="control-label">{{ __('messages.module.customer') }}<span class="compulsory"> * </span></label>
                    <select name="cu" id="cu" class="input-sm form-control" onchange="">
            <option value="">{{ __('messages.select') }}</option>

             @if(!empty($custList))
                                    @foreach($custList as $cu)
                                        <option value="{{ $cu->cu_customer_ID }}">{{ $cu->cu_customer_Shortname }}-{{ $cu->cu_customer_Name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif

                    </select>
                    <input id="hid" type="hidden" name="hid" value=""/>
        </div>
```

> open new window route via onclick

```
 <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" type="button" title="Search Branch" onclick="openNewWindow('{{ route('reporting.branchCheckBoxList', ['cu' ,'state']) }}')" ><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Choose Branch</a>
```

> routes/web.php

```
 Route::get('reporting/branchCheckBoxList/{cuid}/{stid?}','GenReportController@branchCheckBoxList')->name('reporting.branchCheckBoxList');
```

> Controller

```
public function branchCheckBoxList(Request $request) {

         $cuid = $request->get('cuid');
         $stid = $request->get('stid');

    return view('report.BranchCheckBoxList',  compact('cuid','stid'));


    }
```

Comment: where do you pass the id ?

Comment: via onclick open new window sir which is already shown at above

Comment: your route is exact ? and you cannot access only the passed parameters ?

Comment: Where's your javascript of `openNewWindow` function?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot used request in your method arguments considering that you are using a get request in your route, to access those parameters change your controller to this.

```
public function branchCheckBoxList($cuid, $stid = '') {
    $cuid = $cuid;
    $stid = $stid;

    return view('report.BranchCheckBoxList',  compact('cuid','stid'));
}
```

Comment: hi sir...had some progress but when I check console it says state is not defined which is id for select....any idea sir?

Comment: where do you pass the id of it ?

Comment: You cant pass the state of it using that tag only which the state you are passing is dynamic. If it static you can pass it though. If its dynamic then you should JS for that  and redirect to that route.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change','#cu',function(){
{
    var state = $('#state option:selected').val();
    var cu = $('#cu option:selected').val();
    var viewurl = '{{ route("admin.booking.view", [":state",":cu"]) }}';
    viewurl = viewurl.replace(':state',state );
    var finalurl = viewurl.replace(':cu',cu );
    $('a.btn').attr('href',finalurl);
});
```

and in you route

```
Route::get('reporting/branchCheckBoxList/{cuid}/{stid?}','GenReportController@branchCheckBoxList')->name('reporting.branchCheckBoxList');
```

and final in your controller

```
public function branchCheckBoxList($cuid, $stid = '') 
{
     $cuid = $cuid;
     $stid = $stid;

      return view('report.BranchCheckBoxList',  compact('cuid','stid'));
}
```